# SELECT query returns legacy data

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.1

My program does r/w operations on a MariaDB table. There are circumstances why it has to do it in concurrent processes. That's why it does it with multiple connections. After a write (UPDATE query) operation, the then triggered read operation receives legacy values. 
Question is if there is any query or other feature which makes all connections refreshing their data. A reconnect of the reader is actually working, but honestly a bad workaround.

There is no [cache](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/query-cache/) activated. And even if, the description says that an UPDATE will clear the affected sections in the cache.
I'm pretty new to MariaDB, is there any part of the general concept that I miss here?

Comment: Are you saying that the `SELECT` is not started until after all of the writers have `COMMITted`?

Answer (score 0):

The general concept to consider with these issues is "transaction isolation level".

I believe the most plausible explanation with MariaDB would be that both writers and readers work in non-autocommit mode (either `autocommit=0` in `my.cnf` or set explicitly where application opens new connection). In this case, you can give the reader sessions access to newly updated data by issuing their own local `commit;` command instead of full re-connect.

Comment: autocommit is set to 1 by default settings. Also all the connections return '1' by "SELECT @@autocommit". Is there a chance to check if the 'commit' was actually executed?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a better explanation then. My second guess would be that select filter predicates are different from update and therefore selects show different records, not the ones that have been updated. It may be helpful to start making parallel selects from a user and not app session. That would allow to see the problem in a more interactive mode.